# Make UICollectionView scroll right to left?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

The natural direction for a UICollectionView to scroll when set horizontally is from left to right.  Is there any way to reverse this? The simpler the better.

Comment: Use transform: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598194/aligning-right-to-left-on-uicollectionview/27560079#27560079

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean -- if you set the scrolling to horizontal, it scrolls equally well, left and right. If you want it to start it from the right side, you can use this method:

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.theData.count - 1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:NO];
```

This assumes that you have 1 section, and the array populating the collection view is called theData.

Comment: Yes, my apologies for lack of clarification, but that is what I meant -- for it to start at the right side instead of left, and to have the items arranged the same say -- with index 0 as the first item.

Comment: @RobCaraway, If you want what was the item at index 0 to appear on the right, as the first item of a right to left format, I think you would have to reverse your array, or in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, invert the reference to your array index by using (array.count - row -1) instead of row to supply the data to the cells.

Comment: It doesn't allow `paging` to work properly, look at `Mohamed Ayed` answer, his solution is the best

Comment: it scrolls to the item but not the collectionview's edge (if it has padding)

Answer (score 4):

Swift4 solution
in `cellForItemAt` collectionView function

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                let cell = categoryBook.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCategoryCell
                collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:-1,y: 1);

                
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:-1,y: 1);
               }
```

but this solution in some cases `did not work properly if it dose not` you can use ColletctionView  `scrollToItem` method and you can implement it after you reload the data .

```
        self.YourCollectionView.reloadData()
        self.YourCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: NSIndexPath(item: self.YourObjectListData.count - 1, section: 0) as IndexPath, at: .right, animated: false)
```

Comment: This is the best answer cause it allows `paging` to work properly

Answer (score 3):

Same thing for swift:

```
collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: theData.count - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Right, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This Extention

```
extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
open override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
    return true  //RETURN true if collection view needs to enable RTL
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have found using xCode 12.4 with an app that targets iOS 12 that this there seems to be no need to load the items in a different order or do any transforms. The only issue has to do with the initial scroll position. So all I need to do to get things working in both RTL and LTR is the following:

```
collectionView.reloadData {
        if self.collectionView.effectiveUserInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft {
            self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0), at: .right, animated: false)
        }
    }
```