# Aligning right to left on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, right-to-left, uicollectionviewlayout

this is a pretty straightforward question, but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to it on SO (if I missed it, please correct me).

Basically, my question is: ***Is it possible to align `UICollectionView` row contents from right to left instead of from left to right?***

In my research I've seen answers suggesting subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, but I haven't been able to find an example where one was created for right-alignment.

My goal is to have 2 collection views set up like this:

[image: Example]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: i haven't use this but maybe this [link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uicollectionviewrightalignedlayout) will helo you.

Comment: if you ant to follow all the collectionvews/scrollview RT try to follow this link https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/working-with-localization-in-swift-4a87f0d393a4

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can get similar result by performing a transform on the collection view and reverse the flip on its content:

First when creating the UICollectionView I performed a horizontal flip on it:

```
[collectionView_ setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
```

Then subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and in here do the same horizontal flip on its contentView:

```
[self.contentView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
```

Comment: If you have any subviews in your cell, then you have transform it as well. For e.g. `[self.lblTitle setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];`

Comment: @Hemang you sure you flipped the collectionviewcell? This should be sufficient for the context presuming all are sub ores of this

Comment: That's a good trick. Unfortunately the scroll/indicator is inverted too. Another trick is to hide it and scroll to the last item when you reload the data.

Comment: Better answer (with less votes as of now) below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60389015/826946. See the note I added there which sends you to another answer with example code.

Answer (score 111):

Without doing any Xtransform to the collection view, simply forced RTL:

```
YourCollectionView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttribute.forceRightToLeft
```

Comment: this is the solution, working great with texts. the previous solutions not works good with texts

Comment: This technically should be the correct answer.  However - it does appear to stop collection view batch update animations from working (where as the transform hack does not).

Answer (score 35):

In addition to Tawfik's answer:

You can also set UICollectionView's `Semantic` property via Interface Builder:

[image: Storyboard]

More about this property: [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634774/xcode-7-what-is-the-view-semantic-storyboard-setting/32822253#32822253)

Answer (score 30):

you can use this since iOS 11:

```
extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    open override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: You may need to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout. Using this property is a better idea than misusing RTL support which is intended for languages that read right-to-left.

Answer (score 28):

By changing **both** `flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection` and `developmentLayoutDirection`, I was able to achieve a full screen RTL scroll where the first item was all the way to the right, and to reach the last cell, user will need to scroll to the left.

Like so:

```
class RTLCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var developmentLayoutDirection: UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection {
        return UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.rightToLeft
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution thank you!

Comment: @AhmedAbdeen you're welcome! good luck!

Answer (score 23):

For anybody trying to achieve Right to Left layout of `UICollectionView` in Swift

```
//in viewDidLoad
    YourCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)

//in cellForItemAtIndexPath
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
```

Comment: Down-voted this in favor of moving the `UISemanticContentAttribute` response up

Comment: Upvoted because you shouldn't downvote a correct answer

Answer (score 21):

As of iOS 9, Collection Views support RTL according to this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-222/). So it's no longer necessary to create an RTL flow layout (unless you're already using a custom layout).

Select: **Edit Scheme...** > **Options** > **Run** > **Application Language** > **Right to Left Pseudolanguage**

[image]

When you build to Simulator, text will be right-aligned, and your Collection View will be ordered from Right to Left.

[image]

There's a problem though. When `contentOffset.x == 0`, the Collection View scroll position is at the `Left` edge (wrong) instead of the `Right` edge (correct). See this [stack article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130331/uicollectionview-ios-9-issue-on-project-with-rtl-languages-support) for details.

One workaround is to simply scroll the `First` item to the `.Left` (There's a gotcha -- `.Left` is actually on the **Right**, or **Leading** edge):

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(0) > 0  {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
        collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Left, animated: false)
    }
}
```

In my test project, my Collection View was nested inside a Table View Cell, so I didn't have access to `viewDidAppear()`.  So instead, I ended up hooking into `drawRect()`:

```
class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        scrollToBeginning()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        scrollToBeginning()
    }

    func scrollToBeginning() {
        guard collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) > 0 else { return }
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: false)
    }
}
```

To see this in action, check out the [RTL branch on this git repo](https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/HorizontalScrollingCollectionView/tree/RTL). And for context, see this [blog post and its comments](http://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.. to avoid headaches, I just scroll to an arbitrarily large number, like 100000, and it moves to right. Your way is better, tho.

Comment: Down-voted this in favor of moving the UISemanticContentAttribute response up. Very thorough though!

Comment: Saved me!! I just found this issue at the night of deployment and surprisingly I too had the collectionview inside the tableView cell. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: @DougMead why would using UISemanticContentAttribute is better? its not better at all. the uicollectionview already support the rtl. many reported performance issues when keep changing the value of UISemanticContentAttribute. that can happen when u support both rtl and ltr. I would vote for flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection to be  the best solution. in there u can check ur app state. and to make an exceptions for some uicollectionviews. subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout is the solution.

Comment: UISemanticContentAttribute is not the best solution. it says force for some reason. its appears that apple didn't create this to be used this way.

Answer (score 11):

```
extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    open override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: See here for an elaboration on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33130331/826946

Answer (score 8):

Adding below extension worked for me

```
extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    open override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return true  //RETURN true if collection view needs to enable RTL
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it going to affect all of Collection View's direction?

Comment: Yes, You can create a subclass for UICollectionViewFlowLayout and and assign it to collectionView for a particular object.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who has the same question:

I ended up using the [UICollectionViewRightAlignedLayout library](https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewRightAlignedLayout) that @chinttu-roxen-ramani recommended. You can either set it with code:

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[UICollectionViewRightAlignedLayout alloc] init];
```

or through interface builder:

[image: Through interface builder]

I ended up making a couple modifications to the library, but overall it works great.

Comment: hi, i need to use the library too with swift. so could you please tell me about the modification that u applied on the library? 
thanks alot.

Comment: I tried this library in iOS 9, and it produces warnings (which someone also reported on the github project for it). Also it doesn't respect cell dimensions specified in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4):

For iOS **9+**

1. Reverse your collectionView in **viewDidLoad()** with this :

   `myCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)`
2. Reverse-Back your cell (because all things are mirrored) in **cellForItemAt** with this :

   `cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)`

Now content is on right side and scroll starts from right.

Answer (score 2):

`UICollectionView` already support rtl direction if `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is not dynamic.

Changing **Estimate size** to None as the image shows automatically changed the direction of the CollectionView.

[image]

One more issue is to scroll to the end of the collection view after reloading data.

```
extension UICollectionView {
    
    func scrollToEndIfArabic() {
        if Language.shared.isArabic() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.contentOffset
                    = CGPoint(x: self.contentSize.width
                        - self.frame.width
                        + self.contentInset.right, y: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Non of the above answers worked for me.  The main reason was that most of them are not complete.  However, I found this solution from [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83128/how-to-set-uiview-appearance-semanticcontentattribute) by [AlexSerdobintsev](https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/AlexSerdobintsev).

In AppDelegate.cs. First, you have to import the following function

```
[DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.ObjectiveCLibrary, EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
internal extern static IntPtr IntPtr_objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, UISemanticContentAttribute arg1);
```

Then call the function inside FinishedLaunching

```
        var selector = new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setSemanticContentAttribute:");
        IntPtr_objc_msgSend(UIView.Appearance.Handle, selector.Handle, UISemanticContentAttribute.ForceRightToLeft);
```

voila! we are done.
Here is the file after applying the changes:

```
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    [DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.ObjectiveCLibrary, EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
    internal extern static IntPtr IntPtr_objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector, UISemanticContentAttribute arg1);


    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Shell_Experimental", "Visual_Experimental", "CollectionView_Experimental", "FastRenderers_Experimental");
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        ...

        var selector = new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setSemanticContentAttribute:");
        IntPtr_objc_msgSend(UIView.Appearance.Handle, selector.Handle, UISemanticContentAttribute.ForceRightToLeft);

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, all of these answers want to fill the collection view from right to left. For example, if you labeled cells 1, 2, 3, then they would appear in the order 3, 2, 1 in the collection view. In my case I wanted the cells to appear in the order 1, 2, 3 (like text right alignment when the line is not full). In order to do this I created a simple UICollectionViewFlow layout.

```
import UIKit

class RightAlignFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
    {
        guard let attrsArr = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return attrsArr }
        if self.collectionViewContentSize.width > collectionView.bounds.width {
            return attrsArr
        }

        let remainingSpace = collectionView.bounds.width - self.collectionViewContentSize.width

        for attr in attrsArr {
            attr.frame.origin.x += remainingSpace
        }

        return attrsArr
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard let attrs = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) else { return nil }
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return attrs }
        if self.collectionViewContentSize.width > collectionView.bounds.width {
            return attrs
        }

        let remainingSpace = collectionView.bounds.width - self.collectionViewContentSize.width
        attrs.frame.origin.x += remainingSpace
        return attrs
    }

}
```

Comment: This is also giving 3,2,1 only

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers working for me. So finally I fixed my issue with this. I am using RTL for 2 languages(Arabic, French)
Here is my solution

> Use this line for transferring collection view left to right

```
let LangCheck = PPLocalization.sharedInstance.getLanguage(forAPI: true)
if(LangCheck == "ar"){
   CollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1);
}
```

> Use this line to make fit your label inside your collection view cell

```
let LangCheck = PPLocalization.sharedInstance.getLanguage(forAPI: true)
  if(LangCheck == "ar"){
     cell.lbCategoryName.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Needs to do 2 things:

1-

```
extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    open override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

2-

```
self.categoryCollectionView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttribute.forceRightToLeft
```

Comment: Never override anything in an extension. It's undefined behavior. It might work. It might not work. What it multiple parts of the app create extensions that override the same method/property? Which one wins? Again, it's undefined and should never be done.