# Right to Left UICollectionView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to implement right to left flow of cells in my UICollectionView using swift. I tried `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` but it does not work. Here is my method.

```
func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {

    var layOutAttributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes!
    if indexPath.item % 3 == 0 {
        layOutAttributes.frame = CGRectMake((self.namesCollectionView.frame.width * 2)/3 , (self.namesCollectionView.frame.width * 2) / 3, self.namesCollectionView.frame.width/3, namesCollectionView.frame.width/3)
    }

    return layOutAttributes
}
```

Need a direction how can I achieve right to left flow?

Comment: Are you looking for something [answered by this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598194/aligning-right-to-left-on-uicollectionview)?

Comment: Yes. But I have square cell that fills CollectionView. I have already tried the link you gave me but it is not working. I was getting error while setting 'setTransform' on CollectionView.

Comment: use this: YourCollectionView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttribute.forceRightToLeft