# Xcode 7 what is the view "semantic" storyboard setting?

Tags: uiview, storyboard, semantics, ios9, xcode7

I see that iOS9 and xCode7 introduced a new field called "semantic" into storyboard config. A google search did not reveal relevant results on top.

**What is the significance of the view semantic field?**
[image]

Comment: this is complemented by the Direction in Assets.xcassets on each image

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is a new internationalization support in iOS 9, which enables flipping of the interface from left to right and vice versa depending on the current system language. You can choose Arabic language to test it. Arabic is read from right to left, so the interface is flipped.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html) you can read the Apple's guide on it.

The property "Semantic" in the storyboard is a rule which allows the iOS to know if the view should be flipped or not. There are multiple options:

- **Unspecified** - The default value for views. The view is flipped when switching between left-to-right and right-to-left layouts.
- **Playback** - A view representing the playback controls, such as Play, Rewind, or Fast Forward buttons or playhead scrubbers. These views are not flipped when switching between left-to-right and right-to-left layouts.
- **Spatial** - A view representing a directional control, for example a segment control for text alignment, or a D-pad control for a game. These views are not flipped when switching between left-to-right and right-to-left layouts.
- **Force Left-To-Right** - A view that is always displayed using a left-to-right layout.
- **Force Right-To-Left** - A view that is always displayed using a right-to-left layout.

Source - [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UISemanticContentAttribute)

Comment: Any idea about earlier version support ? for ios8

Comment: Apple should give an option that the child view can take parent's semantics

Comment: Still can't understand difference between Playback, Spatial and Force Left-To-Right behaviour..