# Aligning right to left on UICollectionView with contents

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I tried with the following question:

[Aligning right to left on UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598194/aligning-right-to-left-on-uicollectionview) but it's not achieved my goal.

What I was tried:

In `viewDidLoad()`:

```
collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
```

In `cellForItemAtIndexPath()`:

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
```

My current `CollectionView` is on the left, but I want it to look like the `CollecitonView` on the right.

```
dataSource = ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6"]
```

[image]

**Update:**

Change `semanticContentAttribute` of the `collectionView` to `.forceRightToLeft`

```
collectionView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

by  @RajeshKumar answered

I notice. items has spacing too much between two element for example `item1` and `item2` **How can i reduce  that the space and rest of things?** ok for me. on the other hand I tried with `layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0` but it is not worked for me and `item3` not alinement right too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **viewDidLoad()**:

```
 let alignedFlowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout
 collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
 [enter link description here][1]alignedFlowLayout?.horizontalAlignment = .left
```

**@Hemang**  comment worked for me.

If you have any subviews in your cell, then you have transform it as well. For e.g.

```
self.titleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

[AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout)

Answer (score 1):

Change [`semanticContentAttribute`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622461-semanticcontentattribute) of the collectionView to .forceRightToLeft

```
collectionView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

It works

[image]

Comment: I tried but let me  check again because i my collection view in a table view cell

Comment: @NazmulHasan I have 2 collectonviews in same view controller. It works

Comment: **I notice**. items has spacing too much between two element for example `item1 and item2`   how can i fix that rest of things ok for me. on the other hand I tried with `layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0` but it is not worked for me.