# horizontal UIcollectionView Scroll start from right to left

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I do want the view when it loads to show the right cell first then I should scroll left from there I try this code but didn't work

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customCell
        cell.data = self.data[indexPath.row]
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.data.count, section: 0) as IndexPath, at: .right, animated: false)
        return cell
    }
```

like this photo here when the view loads it shows the first right cell

[image]

Comment: Are you getting a crash?

Comment: you mean you want to show last cell when your view loads??

Comment: on I'm not getting crash

Comment: my cells is horizontal when the view loads it will show the left side the right side will be covered by the screen so I want to reverse this, by showing the right cell first

Comment: try changing the semantics - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598194/aligning-right-to-left-on-uicollectionview

Comment: link suggested by @CrackIt  is the answer of your question !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `UICollectionView` scrolls horizontally from right to left equally, you can set your collection view when it appears, to appear scrolled to the maximum right ! so that the user can start scrolling from right to left

`YourCollectionView` is the name of your desired CollectionView

`YourObjectListData` is the Datasource for that collection view

```
self.YourCollectionView.reloadData()
self.YourCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: NSIndexPath(item: self.YourObjectListData.count - 1, section: 0) as IndexPath, at: .right, animated: false)
```

Comment: thats solve the problem but why this method dont work in viewDidLoad or in any of collectionView functions ??

Comment: Because viewDidLoad is only called once in the view lifecycle (the first time the view loads) you could add it in viewWillAppear . Try googling View life cycle methods in iOS

Answer (score -1):

This is not a usual behaviour for a UICollection view, but how about rotating and flipping your collectionView, then the last cell will be your first ;).

if interested check `CGAffineTransform(Rotation angle)` and `CGAffineTransform(TranslationY)`.

Comment: I don't know if you getting my question

Comment: Yea I though you want it to be mirrored, sorry! I did not know that you want it for a different language (Arabic) which is being read from left to right. well I guess you got the answer now :) happy coding.